# Verificação IF e ELSE não está funcionando

Tags: jquery

Galera, estou tentando fazer o seguinte, quando clicar no botão ele verifica se os campos estão vazio, se estiver tudo preenchido ele esconde o form, o problema que ele não está caindo no `else` da verificação: `if (formError) {...} else {...}`.

Quando o formulário estiver preenchido corretamente deveria cair no `else`.

Aqui está um trecho do código.

```
const fields = [...$('.form-group input')];

$.each(fields, function (index) {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        cardForm.removeClass('fadein').addClass('validate-error')
    }
});

const formError = $('.validate-error');

if (formError) {
    formError.bind('animationend', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.animationName === 'nono') {
            formError.removeClass('validate-error').addClass('fadein');
        }
    });
} else {
    cardForm.removeClass('fadein').addClass('form-hide');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está em como você faz a verificação. Quando você executa essa linha:

```
const formError = $('.validate-error');
```

O jQuery retornará um objeto com 0 filhos, mas não um objeto undefined, isso fará com que ele **sempre** entre na verificação do `if`. Para resolver o seu problema, altera a verificação para:

```
if (formError.length > 0)
```

Isso verificará se existe algum campo errado, caso contrário, executará o `else`.

Comment: Nossa, aoskoaksokas, obriGADO bro, toda vez que eu quiser verificar se existe alguma coisa tenho que usar `length > 0` ?, mas muito obrigado irmão

Comment: @BoiProgramador não obrigatoriamente, é que, nesse caso específico, quando você tenta puxar algo com o selector do jQuery, ele sempre vai te retornar um objeto válido, mas, caso você tenha uma variável/constante `undefined`, a verificação que você tentou fazer estaria correta. (:

Comment: @BoiProgramador Pode fazer assim também: `if (formError.length)`, porque se for maior que zero irá validar.

Comment: Ah entendi, vlw rapaziada